# Android Things: display isn't working

Tags: raspberry-pi3, display, android-things

Earlier I was using my `RaspberryPi` with Waveshare LCD and `Raspbian` was installed so there was no issue with display, but now I have `Android Things` SDK so how can I get display working with it? As Waveshare was providing different image for `Raspbian` OS, but how to get its driver for `Android Things` OS?

I was following [this](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A)#Image) and [this](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/RPi-Image-Installation-Guides) for installation on raspberry-pi.

Comment: its [WaveShare 3.2inch RPi LCD (B), 320×240](http://www.waveshare.com/3.2inch-rpi-lcd-b.htm)

Comment: I would encourage you to lookup the datasheet for the display and figure out the Hardware interface it uses to refine your question.

Answer (score 3):

As of now `Android Things` image isn't shipped with a default configuration for display in [`config.txt`](http://elinux.org/RPiconfig) file which is located in the root of your SD card (see the boot partition). The configuration should be added manually. *Look for an appropriate display configuration in the supplied documentation or manufacturer's website*.

For example, in my case for [`Waveshare 5inch 800x480 HDMI LCD (B)`](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/5inch_HDMI_LCD_(B)#Working_with_Raspberry_Pi) the following lines needed to be appended to `config.txt`:

```
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
```

*In fact, the `max_usb_current`, `hdmi_group` and `hdmi_mode` parameters with the values above should work for a wide range of displays from different manufacturers. Screen resolution in `hdmi_cvt` will vary.*

Comment: this is not working with spi based TFT LCD [Waveshare 3.5inch A](http://www.waveshare.com/product/mini-pc/raspberry-pi/displays/3.5inch-rpi-lcd-a.htm) Event from the raspi config.txt documentation, changing hdmi_mode to dpi_mode etc doesn't work :(

Comment: @adadion, yes, by now the solution is for HDMI interface only.

Comment: any idea for spi display? using dpi mode didn't work for me. even I create dts based on waveshare35a.dtb

Answer (score 1):

Latest versions of Android things OS automatically detect any kind of display and reform the settings for it.

So first I will recommend you to check whether your raspberry pi boot up from your sd card or not bcz the latest version i.e 5.0 & 5.1 not working with raspberry pi appropriately (personal experience).

Thus, first check that your raspberry pi give you an ACT light blanking instead of just stable red light.