# Monitor not showing anything after connecting android things flashed image in Rashberry Pi

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, android-things

I have flashed the latest android things image in my Raspberry Pi SD card. And then connected the Raspberry Pi device with external power also connected with my personal monitor.

After turning on the power, I can't see any changes in my monitor. Red light is showing turn on in the Raspberry Pi no green light blinking though.

Comment: If you haven't resolved the issue try [Android Things: display isn't working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163195/android-things-display-isnt-working/41754553#41754553)

Answer (score 2):

This may be due to your Pi can't talk to your display via HDMI properly. Try editing your config file ( which can be found at the root of your storage directory) and append these values.

```
# Force the monitor to HDMI mode so that sound will be sent over HDMI cable
hdmi_drive=2
# Set monitor mode to DMT
hdmi_group=2
# Set monitor resolution to 1024x768 XGA 60 Hz (HDMI_DMT_XGA_60)
hdmi_mode=16
```

For more config options can be found here :
http://elinux.org/RPiconfig

Comment: Finally I could find this file: on the first partition of the sd card, type vfat. Adding those solved my garbled image.