# How do I make the pi-topCEED screen work with Android Things

Tags: raspberry-pi, android-things

When I try [Android Things](https://developer.android.com/things) DP3 with the [pi-topCEED](https://pi-top.com/buy/ceed), the boot screen isn't displayed properly:

[image: boot screen fail]

How can I configure Android Things w/ the appropriate display parameter:

- Resolution: `1366x768`
- Refresh rate: `60hz`

Comment: Have you tried something similar to [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163195/android-things-display-isnt-working/41754553#41754553) with `1366 768` instead of `800 480`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Mount the sdcard image boot partition

  ```
  # on my system
  mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/disk
  ```
- Append the following value to `config.txt`

  ```
  # Define new custom HDMI mode <width> <height> <refresh_rate>
  hdmi_cvt 1366 768 60
  # Select HDMI DMT mode (computer screen)
  hdmi_group=2
  # Select custom mode defined earlier
  hdmi_mode=87
  ```
- Unmount and eject your sdcard

  ```
  umount /dev/disk
  sync
  ```

[image]

([Source](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=24679), [Previous Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163195/android-things-display-isnt-working/41754553#41754553))

Comment: Glad to see [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163195/android-things-display-isnt-working/41754553#41754553) works! :)))))

Comment: @Onik, yep sorry I edited the answer to point to your solution too.