# Android things rainbow screen on raspberry pi

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, android-things

I've followed the instructions in this video to flash my raspberry pi with the Android things image and I got a bit suck.

https://caster.io/lessons/flashing-android-things-firmware-device/

The screen is in a weird rainbow colour as soon as I power it up. I've tried flashing it from the commandline and using Etcher but it's still the same result.

Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the monitor, to make sure it is working very first thing.  You can also access logcat, once  you have connected to the device via adb.

Comment: `to flash my raspberry pi`. A Rapspberry Pi cannot be flashed to begin with,

Comment: @greenapps The image is flashed to the SD card

Comment: Have a look at [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163195/android-things-display-isnt-working/41754553#41754553)

Comment: `The image is flashed to the SD card`. I know. Why are you telling me? Instead you should have updated your post.

Comment: @greenapps Who are you talking to? :)

Comment: Oh this is funny. Sorry... all those people here... Then the last remark was for OP.

Comment: Is it a RasPi3?

Comment: @Booger no ... I realised in the meantime that it's a Pi2 although the person I borrowed it from said it's a 3. Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Things: display isn't working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163195/android-things-display-isnt-working)