# 7" LCD Display not working with Android Things

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, android-things

it's me again with a Android Things question

This time I want to connect a 7" display via HDMI and USB to my Raspberry Pi 3 (running with Android Things 0.5.1)
Here the link to display: [7" HDMI LCD (C)](http://www.waveshare.com/product/mini-pc/raspberry-pi/7inch-hdmi-lcd-c.htm)

I also followed the instruction on the manual and added the lines to the `config.txt` which is located in the root of my sd-card

```
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=1
```

Then I plug in the display. It's definitely on! But the display only shows a black screen.

#### My config.txt

I attached my complete `config.txt`, maybe I'm missing something. And again: I only added the lines shown above

```
kernel=u-boot-dtok.bin
framebuffer_depth=16

# Prevent the firmware from loading HAT overlays now that we handle pin muxing.
# ourselves. See:
# https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/device-tree.md#part3.4
dtoverlay=

dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=audio=on

# pwm and I2S are mutually-exclusive since they share hardware clocks.
dtoverlay=pwm-2chan-with-clk,pin=18,func=2,pin2=13,func2=4
dtoverlay=generic-i2s

start_x=1

# Tell U-boot to always use the "serial0" interface for the console, which is
# set to whichever uart (uart0 or uart1) is set to the header pins. This doesn't
# interfere with the uart selected for Bluetooth.
dtoverlay=chosen-serial0

# Enable skip-init on the UART interfaces, so U-Boot doesn't attempt to
# re-initialize them.
dtoverlay=rpi-uart-skip-init

# Add pin devices to the system for use by the runtime pin configuration driver.
dtoverlay=runtimepinconfig
dtoverlay=uart1
dtoverlay=bcm2710-rpi-3-b-spi0-pin-reorder

# Tell the I2S driver to use the cprman clock.
dtoverlay=bcm2710-rpi-3-b-i2s-use-cprman

# Uncomment to disable serial port on headers, use GPIO14 and GPIO15
# as gpios and to allow the core_freq to change at runtime.
enable_uart=1
core_freq=400

# Enable hardware graphics acceleration.
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d,cma-256
mask_gpu_interrupt0=0x400
avoid_warnings=2

# Support official RPi display.
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231
dtoverlay=rpi-ft5406
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2

# Support custom Waveshare 7inch display
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=1
```

I also checked some other questions like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163195/android-things-display-isnt-working)
But I'm not seeing more information there :(

#### A minor update

I also contacted the manufacturer support. As soon I have more information I will add it here

#### Another update

I just received an email from the manufacturer's support:

> Yes, it can.  However, during the test. With only long HDMI cable such
>   as 1m the LCD could display with new version android things. We don't
>   find the reason.

I just looked into the logcat. As far as I understand it correct, the system tries to connect with the TouchScreen, but has no driver for it.

also these lines look interesting, but I really don't get the problem :(

```
09-19 17:18:00.630 170-261/? E/hwc-gl-worker: Failed to make image from target buffer: EGL_BAD_PARAMETER
09-19 17:18:00.630 170-261/? E/hwc-gl-worker: Composite failed because of failed framebuffer
09-19 17:18:00.630 170-261/? E/hwc-drm-display-compositor: Failed to pre-composite layers
09-19 17:18:00.630 170-261/? E/hwc-drm-display-compositor: Failed to pre-composite for squash all composition -22
09-19 17:18:00.631 170-261/? E/hwc-platform-drm-generic: Failed to close gem handle 0 -1
```

here the complete logcat:

```
--------- beginning of system
09-19 17:17:56.447 311-430/system_process D/UsbHostManager: Added device UsbDevice[mName=/dev/bus/usb/001/004,mVendorId=3823,mProductId=5,mClass=0,mSubclass=0,mProtocol=0,mManufacturerName=WaveShare,mProductName=WaveShare Touchscreen,mVersion=2.0,mSerialNumber=2016-11-06,mConfigurations=[
                    UsbConfiguration[mId=1,mName=null,mAttributes=192,mMaxPower=250,mInterfaces=[
                    UsbInterface[mId=0,mAlternateSetting=0,mName=null,mClass=3,mSubclass=0,mProtocol=0,mEndpoints=[
                    UsbEndpoint[mAddress=129,mAttributes=3,mMaxPacketSize=64,mInterval=1]]]]
09-19 17:17:56.473 311-326/system_process I/ActivityManager: Start proc 1277:com.android.mtp/u0a7 for broadcast com.android.mtp/.UsbIntentReceiver
09-19 17:17:56.501 311-372/system_process E/EventHub: could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse0, Not a typewriter
09-19 17:17:56.509 1277-1277/? W/zygote: Using default instruction set features for ARM CPU variant (generic) using conservative defaults
09-19 17:17:56.551 1277-1284/? I/zygote: Debugger is no longer active
09-19 17:17:56.644 311-372/system_process D/EventHub: No input device configuration file found for device 'WaveShare WaveShare Touchscreen'.
09-19 17:17:56.644 311-372/system_process I/EventHub: New device: id=1, fd=186, path='/dev/input/event0', name='WaveShare WaveShare Touchscreen', classes=0x80000014, configuration='', keyLayout='', keyCharacterMap='', builtinKeyboard=false, wakeMechanism=EPOLLWAKEUP, usingClockIoctl=true
09-19 17:17:56.645 311-372/system_process I/InputReader: Device reconfigured: id=1, name='WaveShare WaveShare Touchscreen', size 16x16, orientation 0, mode 1, display id 0
09-19 17:17:56.645 311-372/system_process I/InputReader: Device added: id=1, name='WaveShare WaveShare Touchscreen', sources=0x00001002
09-19 17:17:56.679 935-935/? I/Binder:311_6: type=1400 audit(0.0:76): avc: denied { ptrace } for scontext=u:r:system_server:s0 tcontext=u:r:priv_app:s0:c512,c768 tclass=process permissive=1
09-19 17:17:57.909 240-240/? I/drm-event-liste: type=1400 audit(0.0:77): avc: denied { read } for path="socket:[8839]" dev="sockfs" ino=8839 scontext=u:r:hal_graphics_composer_default:s0 tcontext=u:r:hal_graphics_composer_default:s0 tclass=netlink_kobject_uevent_socket permissive=1
09-19 17:17:59.010 311-381/system_process W/AlarmManager: Unrecognized alarm listener com.android.server.wifi.WifiConfigStore$1@f0356d5
09-19 17:17:59.028 311-381/system_process D/WifiConfigStore: Writing to stores completed in 18 ms.
09-19 17:18:00.630 170-261/? E/hwc-gl-worker: Failed to make image from target buffer: EGL_BAD_PARAMETER
09-19 17:18:00.630 170-261/? E/hwc-gl-worker: Composite failed because of failed framebuffer
09-19 17:18:00.630 170-261/? E/hwc-drm-display-compositor: Failed to pre-composite layers
09-19 17:18:00.630 170-261/? E/hwc-drm-display-compositor: Failed to pre-composite for squash all composition -22
09-19 17:18:00.631 170-261/? E/hwc-platform-drm-generic: Failed to close gem handle 0 -1
09-19 17:18:08.861 311-1055/system_process D/WificondControl: Scan result ready event
09-19 17:18:30.976 311-325/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
09-19 17:18:30.976 311-325/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
09-19 17:18:31.081 311-325/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
09-19 17:18:31.082 311-325/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
09-19 17:18:31.407 130-130/? W//system/bin/hwservicemanager: getTransportFromManifest: Cannot find entry android.hardware.drm@1.0::IDrmFactory in either framework or device manifest, using default transport.
09-19 17:18:31.409 178-245/? E/DrmHal: Failed to find any drm factories
09-19 17:18:31.413 950-1303/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/DG.WV: Widevine DRM not supported on this device
                             android.media.UnsupportedSchemeException: Failed to instantiate drm object.
                                 at android.media.MediaDrm.native_setup(Native Method)
                                 at android.media.MediaDrm.<init>(MediaDrm.java:216)
                                 at joi.run(:com.google.android.gms:9)
                                 at ius.run(:com.google.android.gms:24)
                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                                 at izo.run(:com.google.android.gms:0)
                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
09-19 17:18:31.707 311-1041/system_process D/WificondControl: Scan result ready event
09-19 17:18:32.104 950-1129/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/SystemServiceRegistry: No service published for: persistent_data_block
09-19 17:18:32.119 1129-1129/? I/Binder:950_3: type=1400 audit(0.0:78): avc: denied { read } for name="/" dev="tmpfs" ino=7244 scontext=u:r:priv_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:device:s0 tclass=dir permissive=1
09-19 17:18:32.129 1129-1129/? I/Binder:950_3: type=1400 audit(0.0:80): avc: denied { read } for name="interrupts" dev="proc" ino=4026532794 scontext=u:r:priv_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc_interrupts:s0 tclass=file permissive=1
09-19 17:18:32.144 950-1129/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_U1rfdkMe/Mr,09vcaQ,w
09-19 17:18:32.150 950-1129/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_U1rfdkMe/Mr,09vcaQ,w
09-19 17:18:34.049 783-1305/com.google.android.gms.persistent I/VacuumService: Vacuum at: now=1505841514048 tag=VacuumService
09-19 17:18:34.223 783-783/com.google.android.gms.persistent I/Auth: [ReflectiveChannelBinder] Successfully bound channel!
09-19 17:18:34.260 130-130/? W//system/bin/hwservicemanager: getTransportFromManifest: Cannot find entry android.hardware.drm@1.0::IDrmFactory in either framework or device manifest, using default transport.
09-19 17:18:34.262 178-178/? E/DrmHal: Failed to find any drm factories
09-19 17:18:34.264 950-1308/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/DG.WV: Widevine DRM not supported on this device
                             android.media.UnsupportedSchemeException: Failed to instantiate drm object.
                                 at android.media.MediaDrm.native_setup(Native Method)
                                 at android.media.MediaDrm.<init>(MediaDrm.java:216)
                                 at joi.run(:com.google.android.gms:9)
                                 at ius.run(:com.google.android.gms:24)
                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
                                 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
                                 at izo.run(:com.google.android.gms:0)
                                 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
09-19 17:18:34.835 950-968/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_U1rfdkMe/Mr,09vcaQ,w
09-19 17:18:34.839 950-968/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_U1rfdkMe/Mr,09vcaQ,w
09-19 17:18:34.968 950-968/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/SystemServiceRegistry: No service published for: persistent_data_block
09-19 17:18:36.507 950-968/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_U1rfdkMe/Mr,09vcaQ,w
09-19 17:18:36.514 950-968/com.google.android.gms.unstable W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/app_U1rfdkMe/Mr,09vcaQ,w
09-19 17:18:36.628 783-1042/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout:
09-19 17:18:36.630 783-1042/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt:    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-19 17:18:36.630 783-1042/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt:    rkw.a(:com.google.android.gms:55)
09-19 17:18:36.752 783-1042/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt: Could not set socket write timeout:
09-19 17:18:36.753 783-1042/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt:    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-19 17:18:36.753 783-1042/com.google.android.gms.persistent W/Conscrypt:    rkw.a(:com.google.android.gms:55)
09-19 17:18:37.310 311-321/system_process I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 56654(2MB) AllocSpace objects, 4(80KB) LOS objects, 42% free, 4MB/8MB, paused 514us total 149.999ms
09-19 17:18:48.913 167-167/? D/WifiHAL: Start get packet fate command
09-19 17:18:48.913 167-167/? D/WifiHAL: createRequest Get Tx packet fate request
09-19 17:18:48.913 167-167/? E/WifiHAL: Failed to register get pkt fate response; result = -95
09-19 17:18:48.914 311-381/system_process E/WifiVendorHal: getTxPktFates(l.1941) failed {.code = ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE, .description = }
09-19 17:18:48.915 167-167/? D/WifiHAL: Start get packet fate command
09-19 17:18:48.915 167-167/? D/WifiHAL: createRequest Get Rx packet fate request
09-19 17:18:48.915 167-167/? E/WifiHAL: Failed to register get pkt fate response; result = -95
09-19 17:18:48.916 311-381/system_process E/WifiVendorHal: getRxPktFates(l.1981) failed {.code = ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE, .description = }
09-19 17:19:00.624 170-261/? E/hwc-gl-worker: Failed to make image from target buffer: EGL_BAD_PARAMETER
09-19 17:19:00.624 170-261/? E/hwc-gl-worker: Composite failed because of failed framebuffer
09-19 17:19:00.624 170-261/? E/hwc-drm-display-compositor: Failed to pre-composite layers
09-19 17:19:00.624 170-261/? E/hwc-drm-display-compositor: Failed to pre-composite for squash all composition -22
09-19 17:19:00.625 170-261/? E/hwc-platform-drm-generic: Failed to close gem handle 0 -1
09-19 17:19:10.975 311-325/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
09-19 17:19:10.975 311-325/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
09-19 17:19:11.702 311-935/system_process D/WificondControl: Scan result ready event
09-19 17:19:16.084 311-325/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
09-19 17:19:16.084 311-325/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
09-19 17:19:16.183 311-325/system_process E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module
09-19 17:19:16.183 311-325/system_process W/android.os.Debug: failed to get memory consumption info: -1
```

### Update - Downgrade to Android Things 0.4.1

I created a new image with Android Thing 0.4.1 and extended the `config.txt`with my device specs, and voilá it's working...

But can maybe someone here help me out to get the display running und 0.5.1? Here is my "updated" `config.txt`

There are some differences between this config and the one I posted above. And of course this config isn't runnable for AT 0.5.1

```
kernel=u-boot-dtok.bin
framebuffer_depth=16
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=audio=on

# pwm and I2S are mutually-exclusive since they share hardware clocks.  To
# enable I2S comment out the pwm line and uncomment the generic-i2s line.
dtoverlay=pwm-2chan-with-clk,pin=18,func=2,pin2=13,func2=4
# dtoverlay=generic-i2s

start_x=1

# Tell U-boot to always use the "serial0" interface for the console, which is
# set to whichever uart (uart0 or uart1) is set to the header pins. This doesn't
# interfere with the uart selected for Bluetooth.
dtoverlay=chosen-serial0

# Enable skip-init on the UART interfaces, so U-Boot doesn't attempt to
# re-initialize them.
dtoverlay=rpi-uart-skip-init

# Uncomment to disable serial port on headers, use GPIO14 and GPIO15
# as gpios and to allow the core_freq to change at runtime.
enable_uart=1
core_freq=400

max_usb_current=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt 1024 600 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=1
```

Comment: @Onik hmm... I think I have been waiting enough ^^ It's connected about an hour. Which value should I use?

Comment: using the latest version of AndroidThings?

Comment: If the latest version is 0.5.1 yes :)

Comment: and where is the code? i.e. do you call `setContentView` ?

Comment: @Blundell my code isn't the issue - I should see the Android Things launch screen or my application (it is working with my monitor)
But I have to check the logcat... maybe I'll get more info there

Comment: If you have no apps installed you'll see the launcher yes. If your app doesn't call `setContentView` then you will see a black screen. I have to ask these questions because you didn't share a MCVE https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: did you try to connect your display to another device (e.g. a laptop) to be sure that the display works / isn't damaged?

Comment: @AlexanderTumanin yes... it works on my laptop

Comment: I have a similar issue with 0.5.1. It works fine with 0.4 but the screen is always black on 0.5.1. I see it thinks the resolution is 16x16 in logcat. I think it has something to do with this release note of 0.5.1: "Automatically detect display settings on Raspberry Pi 3 without the need for edits to the root config.txt file."

Comment: @Onik Now the display doesn't work anymore, I thinks it's an Android Things bug and not a problem of the display (other displays then also don't work anymore) - I added also the info to my question... I would like check other ideas. If the issues is solved with the next AT release I would close this question

Comment: If you find a solution/workaround to the problem or come to conclusion it's a bug, share you findings by answering own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes I managed to get the display running (with the fresh formatted image and the config.txt I posted above)... But from time to time the display stopped working... I then receive this log-message

```
1-01 00:00:18.553 311-334/? I/DisplayManagerService: Display device added: DisplayDeviceInfo{"Built-in Screen": uniqueId="local:0", 16 x 16, modeId 1, defaultModeId 1, supportedModes [{id=1, width=16, height=16, fps=1.0}], colorMode 0, supportedColorModes [0], HdrCapabilities android.view.Display$HdrCapabilities@1d6308, density 240, 96.0 x 96.0 dpi, appVsyncOff 1000000, presDeadline 1000000000, touch INTERNAL, rotation 0, type BUILT_IN, state UNKNOWN, FLAG_DEFAULT_DISPLAY, FLAG_ROTATES_WITH_CONTENT, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
```

And then no other displays (like my monitor, or my tv) aren't also not working anymore.

If the display is detected I receive this message instead:

```
01-01 00:00:18.591 310-332/? I/DisplayManagerService: Display device added: DisplayDeviceInfo{"Built-in Screen": uniqueId="local:0", 1024 x 600, modeId 1, defaultModeId 1, supportedModes [{id=1, width=1024, height=600, fps=43.0}], colorMode 0, supportedColorModes [0], HdrCapabilities android.view.Display$HdrCapabilities@1d6308, density 240, 173.397 x 152.4 dpi, appVsyncOff 1000000, presDeadline 23255814, touch INTERNAL, rotation 0, type BUILT_IN, state UNKNOWN, FLAG_DEFAULT_DISPLAY, FLAG_ROTATES_WITH_CONTENT, FLAG_SECURE, FLAG_SUPPORTS_PROTECTED_BUFFERS}
```

I think this is a bug in Android Things and hopefully this will be fixed with the next release!

If I have any updates, I will update this post.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have the same kit like you, RPi 3 with 7'' display Waveshare and with short and flat HDMI cable. I just tried to start this kit with AT 0.5.1 and it works fine (firstly it shows artefacts, lines and seems to be broken, but after few seconds I could see the Android Things start screen). I followed the description on the [Android Things site](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/raspberrypi.html) for installation. If you read the [release notes](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html) of 0.5.1, there is the following:

**Automatically detect display settings on Raspberry Pi 3 without the need for edits to the root config.txt file.**

But I copied my (*automatically generated*) `config.txt` for you:

```
kernel=u-boot-dtok.bin
framebuffer_depth=16

# Prevent the firmware from loading HAT overlays now that we handle pin muxing.
# ourselves. See:
# https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/device-tree.md#part3.4
dtoverlay=

dtparam=i2c_arm=on
dtparam=spi=on
dtparam=audio=on

# pwm and I2S are mutually-exclusive since they share hardware clocks.
dtoverlay=pwm-2chan-with-clk,pin=18,func=2,pin2=13,func2=4
dtoverlay=generic-i2s

start_x=1

# Tell U-boot to always use the "serial0" interface for the console, which is
# set to whichever uart (uart0 or uart1) is set to the header pins. This doesn't
# interfere with the uart selected for Bluetooth.
dtoverlay=chosen-serial0

# Enable skip-init on the UART interfaces, so U-Boot doesn't attempt to
# re-initialize them.
dtoverlay=rpi-uart-skip-init

# Add pin devices to the system for use by the runtime pin configuration driver.
dtoverlay=runtimepinconfig
dtoverlay=uart1
dtoverlay=bcm2710-rpi-3-b-spi0-pin-reorder

# Tell the I2S driver to use the cprman clock.
dtoverlay=bcm2710-rpi-3-b-i2s-use-cprman

# Uncomment to disable serial port on headers, use GPIO14 and GPIO15
# as gpios and to allow the core_freq to change at runtime.
enable_uart=1
core_freq=400

# Enable hardware graphics acceleration.
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d,cma-256
mask_gpu_interrupt0=0x400
avoid_warnings=2

# Support official RPi display.
dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,ds3231
dtoverlay=rpi-ft5406
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_drive=2
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: I also tried this... (also with a fresh image) but it didn't worked out for me :/ It only worked sometimes after I added the lines from the display's manual to the config

Comment: Sometimes works for AT 0.5.1 too, or only for 0.4.1? I mean, can you surely except the case, that AT 0.5.1 doesn't work at all, not only the display.

Comment: the display always shows me a proper screen if  I attach it to another device... I updated my question with new Info (at the bottom) - I also tried AT 0.4.1

Comment: did you try to connect your RPi3 with 0.5.1 to e.g. TV-Set or other monitor via HDMI? My first time I had troubles with connecting Waveshare to RPi3 and checked if (that time) AT0.3 works with HDMI at all. I mean, maybe you have broken 0.5.1 version

Comment: yes... I did this multiple times and I also created a new image and flashed my sd-card and even tried a different one... I also checked other displays (like my tv or a monitor)

Answer (score -1):

The problem should have been fixed in DP6 ([issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65026541)), which has been [released](https://developer.android.com/things/preview/releases.html#preview-6). I haven't tested it though.